# Can I store row specific data in the ViewHolder?

Tags: android, expand, android-recyclerview

Specifically I have a RecyclerView that displays items that can be expanded when clicked. I need to store the state (expanded/collapsed) of the view somewhere so that reused views are sized correctly.

I was thinking about storing a boolean in the ViewHolder (mIsExpanded), but it doesn't seem to work, here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int pos) {
    final PetrolStation station = this.mData.get(pos);
    final PetrolStationRowHolder rowHolder = (PetrolStationRowHolder) viewHolder;
    rowHolder.setExpanded(rowHolder.isExpanded());
}
```

Following code is in my ViewHolder:

```
public FrameLayout rowContainer; // The root layout of the row
private boolean mIsExpanded; // Stores whether this view is expanded

public void setExpanded(final boolean expanded){
    if(mExpandedLayoutHeight != 0 && mCollapsedLayoutHeight != 0) {
        if (expanded) {
            rowContainer.getLayoutParams().height = mExpandedLayoutHeight;
            mIsExpanded = true;
        } else {
            rowContainer.getLayoutParams().height = mCollapsedLayoutHeight;
            mIsExpanded = false;
        }
        rowContainer.setLayoutParams(rowContainer.getLayoutParams());
    }
}

private boolean isExpanded() {
    return mIsExpanded;
}
```

When I scroll I would expect all the views to be sized correctly, but they are not. If I expand one view via onClick and then scroll there are multiple expanded views, instead of one.

Answer (score 2):

ViewHolders are recycled so they cannot hold row specific information. You need an extra data structure for that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, what I have done as a workaround in the meantime is store all expanded states (isExpanded) in a SparseArray in the Adapter.

This works, but I would still like to know if I can store row related metadata (expanded states etc) in the viewHolder or if I have to create a new data structure for it.